# Hadoop Wordcount Program Compile Error

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop programming.I am using eclipse for hadoop development.I added all jar files through java buildpath when i run my program it is not running and giving this error,so please help me.how to solve error?

14/05/31 23:33:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/05/31 23:33:10 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/05/31 23:33:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-deep/mapred/staging/deep689130586/.staging/job_local689130586_0001
14/05/31 23:33:10 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:deep cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/ already exists
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/ already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1353)
    at hadoop1.MyJob.run(MyJob.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at hadoop1.MyJob.main(MyJob.java:63)

Answer (score 0):

The native libraries failed to load.

This can be due to you are using a 64-bit machine but the hadoop distro is for 32-bit. You can follow the steps here http://www.ercoppa.org/Linux-Compile-Hadoop-220-fix-Unable-to-load-native-hadoop-library.htm to recompile hadoop for 64 bit, and then replace the native libs.

Comment: This link is for hadoop 2.2.0 but my hadoop version is 1.2.1 will it work on that ?Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: The procedure works for 1.2.1 too. However, there is a typo on the original post: the cmd line to make protobuf should be the following `./configure --prefix=\`pwd\`/inst && make && make install`. And, you don't need to patch sources. Beyond that, it takes only a few commands. That's probably the easiest way to get Hadoop to work on your 64-bit machine (suppose you download from the official site). Otherwise, you may find some 64-bit distro or use Amazon EMR.